# Use 2017-02-12T13:30:00Z date in angular2-simple-countdown/countdown

Tags: date, angular, date-format

I want to make a Count down timer using Angular 2 .

I am able to get the Timer using the ans provided to work but i am not able to override the Style of the Timer the Size of the timer i pretty big.

Using like below in template.

```
<count-down [text]="text" units="Days | Hours | Minutes | Seconds " end="{{fixture.date}}"></count-down>
```

Answer (score 0):

howto binding data to your CountDownTimer component, your date from api could be using like this

```
let d = new Date('2017-02-12T13:30:00Z');
let year = d.getFullYear();
let month = d.getMonth();
let day = d.getDate();
```

from there you could binding any property you want.